# Python: TypeError: Only 2-D and 3-D images supported with scikit-image regionprops

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, 2d, scikit-image

Given a `numpy.ndarray` of the kind

```
myarray= 
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

I want to use `scikit-image` on the array (which is already labelled) to derive some properties.

This is what I do:

```
myarray.reshape((11,11))                  
labelled=label(myarray)
props=sk.measure.regionprops(labelled)
```

But then I get this error:
`TypeError: Only 2-D and 3-D images supported.`, pointing at `props`. **What is the problem? The image I am passing to `props` is already a 2D object.**

Shape of `myarray`:

```
In [17]: myarray
Out[17]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: A function that reclassifies the input image according to a binary system.

Comment: Is `label` a shorthand for `skimage.measure.label` or is it a function created by yourself?

Comment: It is a shorthand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this code and I got no errors:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops

myarray = np.random.randint(1, 4, (11,11), dtype=np.int64)
labelled = label(myarray)
props = regionprops(labelled)
```

Sample output:

```
In [714]: myarray
Out[714]: 
array([[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3],
       [3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2],
       [3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2]], dtype=int64)

In [715]: labelled
Out[715]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  0,  0,  2,  2,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4],
       [ 0,  0,  5,  0,  2,  6,  6,  6,  4,  4,  7],
       [ 5,  5,  5,  0,  2,  2,  0,  0,  6,  4,  8],
       [ 9,  5,  0,  0,  0, 10,  0,  4,  0,  4,  4],
       [ 5, 11,  5,  5,  0,  0, 10,  0,  4, 12,  4],
       [ 5, 11,  0,  5,  0,  0, 13,  0,  0, 12, 12],
       [14,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0, 13, 13,  0, 12, 12],
       [ 5,  5,  0,  0, 15, 12,  0, 12, 12, 12, 16],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 15, 15, 12, 12, 17, 17, 17, 16],
       [ 0, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 18, 17, 17, 19, 19],
       [20, 12, 12, 21, 22, 17, 17, 18, 17, 17, 19]], dtype=int64)

In [716]: props[0].area
Out[716]: 1.0

In [717]: props[1].centroid
Out[717]: (1.0, 4.4000000000000004)
```

I noticed that when all the elements of `myarray` have the same value (as in your example), `labelled` is an array of zeros. I also read this in the [`regionprops`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html?highlight=label#skimage.measure.regionprops) documentation:

> **Parameters:**     **label_image** : (N, M) ndarray
>                                  Labeled input image. Labels with value 0 are ignored.

Perhaps you should use a `myarray` with more than one distinct value in order to get meaningful properties...

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue, then after checking Tonechas answer I realized I was importing label from scipy instead of skimage.

```
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label
```

I just replaced it to

```
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
```

And everything worked :)

Comment: I have an issue I have a line `BODY_labels = label(np.array(BODY, dtype=np.uint8))`, however, it is showing an error `BODY_labels = label(np.array(BODY, dtype=np.uint8))
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable'. How to solve this error?